# Show parent and child ine separate box using CSS

Tags: css

Please have a look in the following URL:

```
"http://jsfiddle.net/7rsx0r4h/"
```

I want the output like the output table with border and should be look like separate box but don't want to change my html (div layout).  Also every box i require some space then another box start.

Thanks,
Manish

Comment: I think it's better if you use <ol> and here are the properties applied:border-collapse: separate;
border-spacing: 2px;
border-color: gray;

Comment: No No...I can' change my html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/7rsx0r4h/1/

added outline for the first div

change body to the parent id or class

```
body > div {
    outline:1px solid #4679bd;
}
```

changed border color to white so that it looks like empty space

```
div div {
   border-top: 2px solid white;
}
```

```css
body > div {
  outline: 1px solid #4679bd;
}
div {
  width: 496px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-top: 0;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 120%;
  background: #4679bd;
}
div div {
  font-size: 100%;
  width: auto;
  border: 0;
  border-top: 2px solid white;
  line-height: 250%;
}
```

```html
<p>Divs:</p>
<div>
  <div>1
    <div>1.1
      <div>1.2
        <div>1.2.1</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>2
    <div>2.1
      <div>2.2
        <div>2.2.1</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>
<br />
<p>Table:</p>
<table border="1px" width="500px">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1.1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1.2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1.2.1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3.1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: its not possible for me. becz we are getting this html from another server.